# device [8086:a115] PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Data Link Layer

Tags: intel

The culprit:
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:a115] (rev f1)

Thanks ya'll!

Comment: Could you state that as a question? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.